# How can I draw a vertical line in a table cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, technical-drawing

I hope the explanation will be clear: I have a table with 4 rows, and one of the columns there is a value that is identical in all rows. I want instead of copying it 4 times for each row, just put it in the middle (between the 2nd and 3rd row) and have two vertical lines stretching above and below it up to to the 1st row and 4th row.

I managed to put the number using `multirow` in the middle, but I don't know how to draw the two vertical lines. Any ideas?

EDIT: I want the vertical lines to stretch from the middle above the number -- up and one from the middle below the number down.

Comment: MWE please..... `|c|` does not work for you?

Comment: |c| is not what I am looking for -- because I want the line to stretch from the middle, not at the edges of the cell. I don't have an MWE, because I have nothing that works or doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: in the absence of a MWE, could you provide a picture to what you want? even if you have to draw it by hand :)

Comment: also, why the `tikz` tag?

Comment: @cmhughes because I suspected tikz could help here. and it actually did (see answer below).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An overkill TikZ solution; the common value is vertically centered as required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{cccc}
column 1a &\tikzmark{a}\multirow{4}{*}{\tikzmark{c}50\tikzmark{d}} & column 3a & column 4a \\
column 1b & & column 3b & column 4b \\
column 1c & & column 3c & column 4c \\
column 1d &\tikzmark{b} & column 3d & column 4d \\
\end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
{
\draw let \p1=( $ (c)!0.5!(d) $ ) in ([yshift=9pt]\x1,\y1) -- ([yshift=3pt]\p1|-a.north);
\draw let \p1=( $ (c)!0.5!(d) $ ) in ([yshift=-2pt]\x1,\y1) -- (\p1|-b);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment, **JLDiaz** has proposed the following simplification not requiring the use of `\multirow` and drawing the line with the value in a single step:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \coordinate (#1);}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{cccc}
column 1a &\tikzmark{a} & column 3a & column 4a \\
column 1b & & column 3b & column 4b \\
column 1c & & column 3c & column 4c \\
column 1d &\tikzmark{b} & column 3d & column 4d \\
\end{tabular}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
{\draw ([yshift=1ex]a) -- (b) node[midway,fill=white] {50};}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: an overkill, but works quite well... thanks!

Comment: @Gonzalo_Medina:  I would simplify that solution by omitting the multirow, leaving the first row simply as: `column 1a &\tikzmark{a}& column 3a...`. After this, the final line is drawn in a single stroke as `\draw ([yshift=1ex]a) -- (b) node[midway,fill=white] {50};`. <br/>Also, my `\tikzmark` definition uses `[coordinate]` option for the empty node.

Comment: @JLDiaz nice simplification. I've added it to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example which achieves the effect by create *faux* columns in which a `multicolumn` command will be called.

Here's MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Create faux columns 2 and 3.

The hspaces in the first line are to make the centering work correctly.

\begin{tabular}[t]{cc|ccc}%
 1a & \hspace*{1em} & \hspace*{1em} & 3 & 4 \\
 1b & & & 3 & 4 \\
 1c & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & 3 & 4 \\
 1d & & & 3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

Comment: this is what i to tried to get. btw is there a way to vertically center the content of second column automatically. i am thinking of some way to combine Gonzalo's and your solution.

Comment: this is a simple solution, and *almost* works but not quite -- because value is not centered between the 2nd row and 3rd row. thanks, though!